# lines to connect geom_jitter points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to connect the points from `geom_jitter()`.

```
 df<-data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
           y = c(1, 1, 2 , 3, 6, 5), 
           z = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")) 
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = z)) + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  geom_line()
```

Now the lines and points are not connected.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this but if you want to connect them then why do you use `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point` ? `ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()`

Comment: `geom_jitter` is used to visualize the distribution of values for a categorical variable.

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah. My real graph has error bars, I would like to show them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(df %>% mutate(x = jitter(x), y = jitter(y)), 
       aes(x = x, y = y, col = z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, @Jon Spring. For my purpose, `x = jitter(x)` alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Add jitter (some bias) to your data and then plot biased one.